# Why do we use "intent.getParcelable()" on "BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE"?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am learning about bluetooth in android.

I am wondering why do we use `intent.getParcelable()` on `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE` when its return type is string?

Why don't we use `intent.getStringExtra`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it isn't returning `String`, its `BluetoothDevice` (which `implements Parcleable`)

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Comment: But when I see the return type, its string

Comment: well, it is not, have you tried posted line to fetch `BluetoothDevice`? maybe at some point you are using `.toString()` method, also framework is using this method under the hood oftenly. e.g. when you make some `Log.i("TAG", "device: " + device);` it will behave exacly same as `Log.i("TAG", "device: " + device.toString());` as `BluetoothDevice device` isn't `String` but this object is "forced"/normalised to be a part of `String` (for log)